# SDL2 Error "Error Creating Renderer: Renderer already associated with window". I want to put a background for my player

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL_timer.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1280 
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 720
#define SPEED 250 
#define FPS 60

int main(int argc,char* args[])
{
    SDL_Surface *imageSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *windowSurface = NULL;
    /*Initializing Graphics and Timer System*/
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_TIMER)!=0){
        printf("Error Initializing SDL: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    } 
    /*Creating a Window*/
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("HELI",
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                               SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    if(window == NULL){
        printf("Error Creating Window: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    /*Creating a Renderer, Which Sets Up the Graphics Hardware*/
    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,render_flags);
    if(renderer == NULL){
        printf("Error Creating Renderer: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    /*Loading the Player image into memory using SDL Image Library Function*/
    SDL_Surface* player = NULL;
    player = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/betmon69/Documents/Heli/Images/player.bmp");
    if(player == NULL){
        printf("Error Creating Player\n");
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }   
    /*Loading the Player Image Data Into the Graphics Hardware's Memory*/
    SDL_Texture*  player_tex = NULL;
    player_tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,player);
    SDL_FreeSurface(player);
    if(player_tex == NULL){
        printf("Error Creating Player Texture: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    /*Structure to Hold the Position and Size of the Player*/
    SDL_Rect dest;
    /*Get the Dimensions of Player*/
    SDL_QueryTexture(player_tex,NULL,NULL,&dest.w,&dest.h);
    dest.w;
    dest.h; 
    /* Start the Player in Center of Screen(ami nije korbo eta)*/
    float x_pos = (SCREEN_WIDTH - dest.w)/2;
    float y_pos = (SCREEN_HEIGHT - dest.h);
    float x_vel = 0;
    float y_vel = 0;

    /*Keep Track of Which Inputs are given*/
    int up = 0;
    int down = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;

    /*Animation Loop*/
    SDL_Event event;
    imageSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("/home/betmon69/Documents/Heli/Images/background.bmp");
    if(imageSurface == NULL){
        printf("SDL Could Not Load Background! SDL Error: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
    }
    bool running = true;
    while(running){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            switch(event.type){
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    switch(event.key.keysym.scancode){
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_W:
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_UP:
                            up = 1;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_A:
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT:
                            left = 1;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_S:
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN:
                            down = 1;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_D:
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT:
                            right = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    break; 
                case SDL_KEYUP:
                    switch(event.key.keysym.scancode){
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_W:
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_UP:
                            up = 0;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_A:
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT:
                            left = 0;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_S:
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN:
                            down = 0;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_D:
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT:
                            right = 0;
                            break;
                }
                break;
            }   
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface,NULL,windowSurface,NULL);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        /*Determine the Velocity*/
        x_vel = 0;
        y_vel = 0;
        if(up && !down) y_vel = -SPEED;
        if(down && !up) y_vel = SPEED;
        if(left && !right) x_vel = -SPEED;
        if(right && !left) x_vel = SPEED;
        /*Update Positions*/
        x_pos += x_vel/60;
        y_pos +=y_vel/60;
        /*Collision Detection with Borders*/
        if(x_pos<=0) x_pos = 0;
        if(y_pos<=0) y_pos = 0;
        if(x_pos>=SCREEN_WIDTH - dest.w) x_pos = SCREEN_WIDTH - dest.w;
        if(y_pos>=SCREEN_HEIGHT - dest.h) y_pos = SCREEN_HEIGHT - dest.h;
        /*Set the Positions in the Structure*/
        dest.y = (int) y_pos;
        dest.x = (int) x_pos;
        /*Clear the Window*/
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        /*Draw the Player to the Window*/
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,player_tex,NULL,&dest);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_Delay(1000/60);
    }
    /*Clean Up Resources Before Exiting*/
    SDL_DestroyTexture(player_tex);
    SDL_FreeSurface(imageSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(windowSurface);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

So in my code you can see that i have created player which can freely roam around and collision also happens. I just want to create a background for the player i just have created. But the background doesn't create. I have used SDL_Surface and also used SDL_GetWindowSurface(). but the error i am getting is "Error Creating Renderer: Renderer already associated with window". What should i change to have a background for my player? Please Help.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` with a window you're going to create a renderer on?  That's specifically prohibited by [the documentation](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/eaac8e676d45/include/SDL_video.h#l840).

Comment: @genpfault I am new to SDL2. Can you give me an idea how can I process the background? Should I make another surface for background and use SDL_Texture?

Comment: Update: Thanks alot for the help. Tried myself. And the background came.